# How to include a row number but show a tie?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Say I have the query below:

```
WITH TEMP AS
  (
     select 1 as id, 4 as value
     UNION
     SELECT 2, 53
     UNION
     SELECT 3, 1
     UNION
     SElECT 4, 474
     UNION
     SELECT 5, 53
  )

  SELECT *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY value)
  FROM TEMP
```

This returns the following:

```
3   1   1
1   4   2
2   53  3
5   53  4
4   474 5
```

I would like two rows with 53 to have the same row number (3) and the final row to keep it's row number of 5.  I assume this cannot be done using ROW_NUMBER.  Can anyone point me in the right direction to get me started on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using `ROW_NUMBER`, you want to use `RANK`.

```
  SELECT *,   
      RANK() OVER (ORDER BY value)   
  FROM TEMP
```

[RANK (T-SQL) MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx)

Comment: @OMGPonies No it's not.  The user wants the gaps in ranking.  If the user is looking for a result of `1; 2; 3; 3; 5` then `RANK` would be appropriate.  `DENSE_RANK` would give `1; 2; 3; 3; 4`.

Comment: @OMGPonies I think to address OP's requirement ("53 to have the same row number (3) and the final row to keep it's row number of 5."), RANK is the apt choice